# How do I process tuples through a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I am currently attempting [a contest problem](https://dmoj.ca/problem/anoisyclass) that involves passing tuples through vectors to compare with other tuples. Is there a way to do this in C++? Or, perhaps, is there a more efficient way to solve this problem without tuples? Here is what I have so far.

```
int aNoisyClass()
{
    int a, b, n, m;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    for (int x = 0; x < m; x++)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        make_tuple(a, b);
    }
    while(true)
    {
    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm having a hard time trying to wrap my head around how to compare every tuple with all others and an even harder time figuring out how to do it within the time limit. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) to solve this problem. That's enough of a problem spoiler.

If you still can't figure out how to solve it, see spoiler [here](https://justpaste.it/3kjt2).

Comment: I don't think you necessarily have to implement a graph structure. As far as I understand the problem, this is effectively a cyclicity test. Iff your input graph is a DAG, you can partially order it and you're fine.

Comment: @bitmask Well, it requires the 'concept' of Graphs, that's what I actually meant in the first place.